# What is the correct way to send validation errors back to a Vue component from a Laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

[I've revised this question a bit to consider another approach. I also apologize if this question seems unduly long. I suppose I'm a bit long-winded but I'm really just trying to be very clear.]

I am fairly new to Laravel, Vue and Vuetify but, after a lot of struggling, I've gotten my CRUD app to work with MySQL, at least as long as I pass my Controller good data. But now I'm struggling with the right way to do error handling.

I use Vuetify to do my front-end error checking and it seems to work very well. I've been able to write validations for every condition I could think of and display a meaningful error message where it is most appropriate to show it. I know I need to do the same validations in my Laravel controller back-end and writing good validations there seems pretty straightforward too. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to communicate a back-end validation error to my Vue component.

My CRUD app is doing the classic To Do List. One of the fields on my input form for adding a new task is the due date for the new task and one of the edits that should be done on both the front-end and the back-end is that the due date can't be in the past. I've "accidentally" omitted that check on the front-end but have included it on the back-end to be sure the back-end will detect it when I choose a past date as my due date. My Laravel controller detects that as intended and my browser console shows this:

[image: error message]

Clearly, the validations in the controller are working and they have correctly detected the problem with the due date. Now, my problem is how to get the relevant information to my Vue component and, when relevant (as it is in this case), how do I display it to my user?

All the examples I could find that were for Laravel apps that use Vue components had them using the `then` and `catch` blocks to deal with the Axios response and error information. The other option that occurs to me is to access the error bag generated by the Laravel controller but I can't find any information on how that could be done in a Vue component so it looks like I have to take the Axios approach....

I cannot figure out how to display the relevant information from the Response Payload in my Vue component *in the `catch` block*. In every example I've found, the Response is returned to the `then` block and the Error is returned to the `catch` block but when there is an error, the `then` block never gets executed in favour of the `catch` block. But when the `catch` block executes, it can't *see* the Response so it can't show me anything from the Response, like the validation message.  All the searching I've done for answers has left me more confused than enlightened since many answers assume the validation errors are going back to a Laravel blade while others are for much older versions of Laravel. (I am running Laravel 8.x.)

I know that not all errors will be user errors. For example, the database could be down, making all access to the database impossible. I also need to note those situations. The user needs to be told something - perhaps "The database is down. Please try again later." - and the admins need to be advised that the database is down. I'm still trying to figure out the best way to do that but am leaning towards ErrorBoundary as the solution.

For the moment, I'll be delighted if someone can explain how to get the information I want from the Response payload when there is a user-fixable error. Some advice on how to handle situations where the error is NOT user-fixable would be even better.

Here is the relevant bit of my Insert logic in the Vue component:

```
/* We are creating a new item so determine the id for the new item. It should be 
   one greater than the highest id currently in the array. Every id of an existing
   task should always be at least 1. */
console.log(this.name + ".save() - saving a new item");
var highestTaskID = 0; //must be one less than the lowest possible id value
for (let todo of this.todos) {
    if (todo.id > highestTaskID) highestTaskID = todo.id;
}
var newTaskID = highestTaskID + 1; /* Calculate the ID of the new task. */
this.editedItem.id = newTaskID;  
this.form.id = this.editedItem.id;
this.form.description = this.editedItem.description;
this.form.status = this.editedItem.status;
this.form.priority = this.editedItem.priority;
this.form.due = this.editedItem.due;
let data = new FormData();
data.append('id', this.form.id);
data.append('description', this.form.description);
data.append('status', this.form.status);
data.append('priority', this.form.priority);
data.append('due', this.form.due);
axios.post('/task', data)
     .then((res) => {              
        console.log(this.name + ".save() - response from insert (then): " + res);
        this.snackbarMessage = "Created new task";
        this.showMessageSnackbar = true;
        this.showTable = true; //start showing ToDo table again 
        this.form.reset();
        this.getTasks();
        })
     .catch((error) => {
        console.log(this.name + ".save() - response from insert (catch): " + res);
        console.log(this.name + ".save() - error: " + error);
        this.snackbarMessage = "Failed to create new task";
        this.showMessageSnackbar = true;
        this.showTable = true; //start showing ToDo table again
        })
```

This is the store() method in my TaskController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        app('debugbar')->info('TaskController.store() started');

        $today = date('Y-m-d');

        $this->validate($request, [
            'description' => ['required', 'min:5', 'max:191'], 
            'status' => ['required'],
            'priority' => ['required'],
            'due' => ['required', 'after-or-equal:' . Date('Y-m-d')]
        ],
        [
            'description.required' => 'You must provide a non-blank task description',
            'description.min' => 'The task description must contain at least 5 characters',
            'description.max' => 'The task description must not exceed 191 characters',
            'status.required' => 'You must provide a task status',
            'status.in' => 'You must choose a task status from: Pending or Completed',
            'priority.required' => 'You must provide a task priority',
            'priority.in' => 'You must choose a task priority from: Low, Medium or High',
            'due' => 'You must provide a task due date',
            'due.after_or_equal' => 'You must provide a due date greater than or equal to today'
        ]
        );
        app('debugbar')->info('TaskController.store() validations completed');

        Task::create($request->all());
    }
```

Should I be logging any and all errors I detect in the Controller itself, rather than in the Vue component? That might be a lot easier in some respects, although I still have to be able to detect which errors can be passed back to the user for them to handle and when I simply have to tell them to try later because the app isn't working fully yet.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd advise using axios' Response Interceptor which is essentially a callback that gets executed every time a request has been completed so you don't have to do error handling on each and every request.

Create a new file (for example `axiosInstance.js`)

```js
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://example.com/api',
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    return response;
}, (error) => {    
    switch(error.response.status) {
        case 422:
            // Here you will be able to process Laravel Validation Errors.
            // You can for example display an error message using your favorite library

            console.log("Error Message: " + error.response.data.message);
            console.log("Error Object: " + error.response.data.errors);
            break;
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
}

export default axiosInstance;
```

As you can see you can access your response by using `error.response`. This works for `catch` blocks in simple axios requests aswell.

```js
axios.get('https://example.com/xyz').catch(e => {
   console.log(e.response);
});
```

The above interceptor in my first code block will do special handling for all Laravel Validation Errors since those are returned using HTTP Status 422 (Unprocessable Entity) by default.
To use it, instead of doing `axios.get()` you can do:

```js
import axiosInstance from './axiosInstance.js';
axiosInstance.get('https://example.com/xyz');
```

The logic you defined in the catch block of the interceptor will then be executed every time a request that was initiated using `axiosInstance`. You can also append `.catch()` again to the request to handle additional logic if a specific requests fails.

To handle additional error types, extend the interceptors `switch` conditional statement. For example, exceptions like "The database is not available" are returned with status code 500 by Laravel. Usually, a simple message is then available to display to the user by using `error.response.data.message`.

---

tl;dr
This is what you could do achieve what you are trying to do using your code:

```js
axios.post('/task', data)
     .then((res) => {              
        console.log(this.name + ".save() - response from insert (then): " + res);
        this.snackbarMessage = "Created new task";
        this.showMessageSnackbar = true;
        this.showTable = true; //start showing ToDo table again 
        this.form.reset();
        this.getTasks();
        })
     .catch((error) => {
        console.log(this.name + ".save() - response from insert (catch): " + error.response);
        // Given that your erroneous response contains 'message' (like laravel validation errors do):
        console.log(this.name + ".save() - error: " + error.response.data.message); 
        this.snackbarMessage = "Failed to create new task";
        this.showMessageSnackbar = true;
        this.showTable = true; //start showing ToDo table again
        })
```

Comment: This looks very promising but I think I'm going to have some followup questions, maybe several, unless perhaps you can point me to a full example so that I can see how the pieces you've given me fit in? My issue feels like it should be routine but nothing I found in my searches that resembles this solution. Where did YOU learn this technique? Or did you come up with it on your own? This feels like the kind of thing that should be in the Laravel docs, in tutorials and videos but I haven't seen anyone tackle my issue.

Comment: To be honest, the Laravel docs lack a lot to cover. [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-xhr-requests-and-validation) you can see Laravel returns Status Code 422 for XHR Requests triggering validation errors by default. I've learned about axios response interceptors a while ago in a medium post. [This one](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/axios-instance-interceptors-682868f0de2d) explains a bit more about Interceptors. I've then adapted it to my needs over the time. As with everything, there are many ways to reach your goal. Feel free to ask more specific question here.

Comment: Yes, the Laravel docs fail to cover some important things altogether. (I may make some efforts to improve them via a back-channel I have but that will take time.) I really want to get this working but I need to take a few days to deal with pressing matters so I'll work on the code from your hints and ask here again if things aren't working. Thanks VERY much for your help!!